# Why are @HostBinding, @HostListener, and @Input not working in my Angular app?

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble incorporating @HostBinding, @HostListener, and @Input.  It's supposed to interchange between images when you hover over and hover out of the image area.  It seems like it should work, but it doesn't.  Any help is appreciated.

This is from the free and highly rated book 'Angular 4: From Theory to Practice' which you can get off Amazon.  It is the 'end of chapter' activity for the chapter on 'Custom Directives'.

Here's my plunker link for where I'm currently at in the problem:  http://plnkr.co/edit/MO2m8F4A3PLIIzMIbMD5?p=preview

and here is the code here as well:

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {
    Component,
    Directive,
    Renderer,
    HostListener,
    HostBinding,
    ElementRef,
    NgModule,
    Input,
    Output,
    EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Directive({
  selector: "[ccRollover]"
})
class RolloverImageDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){

  }
  @HostBinding('src') private image: string;

  @Input('ccRollover') images: Object = {
    initial: 'https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=201',
    over: 'https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=202'
  };
  @HostListener('mouseover') onMouseOver() {
    this.image = this.images.over;
  }
  @HostListener('mouseout') onMouseOut(){
    this.image = this.images.initial;
  }
  //TODO: Flesh out this directive
  //TODO: HINT - Use ngOnChanges()
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
<img ccRollover[images]="{
  initial:'https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=201',
  over:'https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=202'
}"/> 
`
})
class AppComponent {
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RolloverImageDirective
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/pWrPm6ErxU4S57dGrn8l?p=preview

Comment: what is that you are trying to do?

Comment: @yurzui thank you for your working solution with a plunker link.  I can understand everything you changed, except for the way you incorporated HostBinding.  Why can't I just bind directly to a string variable, as I tried, instead of going through a function of sorts?  Which I don't understand how it knows to bind from the _image variable in your solution.  thanks.

Comment: @yurzui I found the reason why I wasn't able to see the binding directly to a string variable was because I had no initial image from which the HostListeners to do their binding upon.  The solution in the book uses 'ngOnChanges()' to initialize the initial image upon page initialization.  Then the HostListeners have something to work upon.

Comment: Though, @yurzui, if you could, would you please describe how your binding solution works where you utilize a function that returns this._image.  As it is perplexing to me.

Comment: Sorry @Aravind, I added to the description the following: "It's supposed to interchange between images when you hover over and hover out of the image area."

Answer (score 0):

is

```
  @Input('images') images: Object = {..} //<--images, not  ccRollover
```

is

```
<img ccRollover [images]="{..} //<--see the "space" between ccRollover and [images]
```

Comment: I incorporated both of your modifications and it still doesn't work.  

You can give your solutions a try before submitting your thoughts by going to the linked 'plunker' page.

Comment: Sorry @Rune, I has done and work. I've just done again and work. Anyway, check the plunker of yurzui